# wp_update_user not working on live server

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I have a problem. This code creating for change WP user password and user display name. My code is working on my local-host but same code is not working live server. what is the problem of my code? always showing error!

```
function pass_change_form()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $user_email     = $_POST["user_email"]; 
    $full_name      = $_POST["full_name"];
    $password       = $_POST["password"];
    $re_password    = $_POST["re_password"];

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'");
    //var_dump($results);
    $id         = $results[0]->ID;
    $user_login = $results[0]->user_login;
    $user_email = $results[0]->user_email;

    if(empty($re_password)){
        $user_data = wp_update_user( array( 
                        'ID'            =>  $id, 
                        'user_login'    =>  $user_login,
                        'user_email'    =>  $user_email,
                        'display_name'  =>  $full_name ) );

                        if ( is_wp_error( $user_data ) ) {
                            echo 'Error';
                        } else {
                            echo 1;
                        }
    }
    else{
        $user_data = wp_update_user( array( 
                        'ID'            =>  $id, 
                        'user_login'    =>  $user_login,
                        'user_email'    =>  $user_email,
                        'user_pass'     =>  $re_password, 
                        'display_name'  =>  $full_name ) );

                        if ( is_wp_error( $user_data ) ) {
                            echo 'Error';
                        } else {
                            echo 0;
                        }
    } 
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pass_change_form', 'pass_change_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pass_change_form', 'pass_change_form');
```

Comment: Is the users table on your live site `wp_users`? If not that might be the issue.

Comment: I am just curious, there is default WordPress functionality which does exactly what you are trying to do. Why don't you use that?

Comment: @stevenkellow Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Berend de Groot mentions in his comment above, why rewrite the password change process? WP has a function built in that would do this for you. See `wp_set_password()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password for information on how to use that.

As for your code, the below will do the exact same, just rewritten to be cleaner and use the already existing function.

```
function pass_change_form() {
    $user_email     = $_POST["user_email"]; 
    $password       = $_POST["password"];
    $re_password    = $_POST["re_password"];

    $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);

    // Why use empty() to check a string? Is 're_password' an array?
    if($user && !empty($re_password)) {
        wp_set_password($re_password, $user->ID);
    }

    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pass_change_form', 'pass_change_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pass_change_form', 'pass_change_form');
```